# Legacy database mixes primary and foreign keys: update error "The property is part of the object's key information and cannot be modified"

Tags: oracle, entity-framework-4, primary-key, legacy-database

Consider the following tables:

```
create table master  
( nr number(10,0) identity primary key
  lastmodified date
  scn number(12,0)  -- update from sequence with every update
)
create table details
( nr number(10,0) primary key
  linenum number(3,0) primary key
  <more details>
  scn number(12,0)  -- update from sequence with every update
)
```

Table Details has a foreign key from column nr to column nr. Both tables are mapped to entities with the primary database keys as entity keys. There is a one-to-many relation between Master and Detail.

When I add a master with a single detail to the EF context and call SaveChanges, the nr field in the master is determined by a trigger in the database, returned to EF, written into the details.nr property and saved in the details table. Well done, EF!

But when I try to update one of the details fields in the details entity adn call SaveChanges, I get the error "The property 'Nr' is part of the object's key information and cannot be modified." Apparently EF tries to update the Nr field from the related Master. Which is not modified, of course.

What is the best way to work around this limitation? Adding a new entity key field and changing the primary key columns is not an option.

*Disclaimer: I wrote the code by hand to focus on the issue, it may not compile but I hope you get the point.*

**Update**: I think (hope...) that the problem is solved. If I set the SCN field in the Detail entity to both ConcurrencyMode=Fixed AND StoreGeneratedPattern=Computed, the error message about the Nr field appears. If I set the SCN fields to ConcurrencyMode=Fixed and StoreGeneratedPattern=None, the SaveChanges returns without errors.

Comment: What is the value of StoreGeneratedPattern in all these primary key properties?

Comment: The Nr field in the master is set to StoreGeneratedPattern=Identity. In the detail both Nr and Linenum have no attributes. There is another "SCN" field in both tables, which is updated from an Oracle sequence with every write, and that is set to ConcurrencyMode=Fixed.